# how to send an email when someone logs into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I would like an email sent to me if a someone has logged into the database. My config to connect and log in is below.

```
     <?php 
session_start();
    require_once('connect.php');

    // Retrieve username and password from database according to user's input
    $input_username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '".$input_username."'" ); 

    // Check username and password match
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($login);
    if (mysql_num_rows($login)) {
            if($row['password'] === md5($_POST['password'])){
                 $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username']; // store in session
                 $sql = "UPDATE user SET logindate = NOW() WHERE username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']) . "'";
                 mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in SQL: " . mysql_error()); 

    }
    else{
            // Invalid login
            echo header('Location: loginerror.php');
                  exit;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Simple, read this -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Can you explain why you need this?

Comment: So every time this script gets run, you send an email??

Comment: @Jleagle when a person logs in i get an email saying a person has logged in

Comment: @Fabian do i put this at the very start?

Comment: replace your `if ($rowcount == 1) { }` with the code i provided, this should work.

Comment: @Fabian have edited my code to a new login

Comment: @Lukus Then just add the mail function I provided in your if() where you check if the user has logged in successfully. Just make sure you redirect AFTER you sent the mail!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply send mails with the PHP [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function.

You may want to add it like this, if you want to recieve an email every time a user logged in:

```
if ($rowcount == 1) {

    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];

    $headers  = "From:Me <no-reply@example.com>\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: no-reply@example.com\r\n";
    $email_to = "your@emailadress.tld";
    $subject = "Someone logged in!";
    $message = "User ".$_POST['username']." logged in!";
    mail($email_to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    header("Location: securedpage.php");

}
```

To check whether the mail function was successful or not you can use:

```
if(mail($email_to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {

    // mail function was successful

} else {

    // error; mail function was NOT successful

}
```

**Edit:**

Just a note: You do a query twice and in the second one you don't use escaped data. You should remove your first one and change the second one to the code below. Also use mysql_real_escape string for the password:

```
$input_password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbuser WHERE (username = '" . $input_username . "') AND (password = '" . md5($input_password) . "')",$db);
```

Comment: Just a note that relying on the return value of mail() is not a guarantee that the mail has sent. It is about the `sendmail` program that do the job.

Comment: @Lukus hm? Have you been able to send a mail on successful login?

Comment: what's the error? You may also want to user `if (mysql_num_rows($login) > 0)`

Comment: also you're using `echo header('Location: loginerror.php');` but it should be `header('Location: loginerror.php');` without **echo**

Comment: And you're missing a brace for this if: `if($row['password'] === md5($_POST['password'])){`